# Which Ubuntu for Toshiba Satellite M70-168

Tags: system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu on an old ToshibaSatellite M70-168

```
type: Technologie Mobile Intel® Centrino™ Pentium® M 740
      Intel® PRO/Wireless 2200BG et Chipset Intel® 915GM Express
clock speed: 1.73 GHz
front side bus: 533 MHz
L2 cache: 2 Mo
standard: 512 Mo
maximum memory: 2,048 Mo
Ram type: DDR2 RAM
```

Which version should I chose ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Ubuntu you're more lucky than with Windows. You can try before install any Ubuntu version you want. You can create a Ubuntu LiveDVD or LiveUSB and try everything in live mode without damaging anything inside your PC. Maybe start with 14.04 as a reference. See how fast it goes, and then move up (or down) a version or two.

You can also try other Ubuntu flavors: liter (Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Cubuntu, UbuntuMate) or heavier (Kubuntu).